# Which form event should I use to pop up a login form?

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

Before the user makes use of the main form, I want to pester them to enter their username, password, and siteNumber.

Should I invoke a ShowDialog on the login form from the Main form's Load(), Activated(), GotFocus(), or Validate() events? Or should I just invoke the login form from the main form's constructor?

This is a Windows CE app, and those are the only options I have, event-wise (there is no "Shown" event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered prompting via `ShowDialog` *before* you even get to the main form?

Put the code right in the `Main()` someplace before the Application.Run(new MainForm()).

Works fine, I've done this before.