# Is There a Way to Remove the Delay between an Interspersed Login form and the Main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce, formclosing

Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867278/which-form-event-should-i-use-to-pop-up-a-login-form) to create my login form in the project's Main method like so:

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Unhandled;

    frmLogin loginForm = new frmLogin();
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // If they hit "Close" just use the default values for now (for testing)
        HHSConsts.userName = "duckbilled";
        HHSConsts.pwd = "platypus";
        HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = "Packers20Seahawks19";
    }
    else
    {
        HHSConsts.userName = loginForm.UserName;
        HHSConsts.pwd = loginForm.Password;
        HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = loginForm.SiteNumber;
    }
    loginForm.Dispose();

    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}
```

The login form has two buttons, "OK" and "Close":

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HHSConsts.userName = textBoxUsername.Text.Trim();
    HHSConsts.pwd = textBoxPwd.Text.Trim();
    HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // TODO: Prevent shutdown if "OK" is selected and there are any missing or bogus values?
    this.Close();
}

private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

This works pretty fair, but there is a definite delay between the login form closing and the main form displaying. Is there a way to close this gap so that the interval is not so noticeable?

### UPDATE

Replacing this:

```
Application.Run(new frmMain());
```

...with this:

```
Application.Run(new Form());
```

...in Program.cs results in the following:

Clicking the OK button on the login form: app closes (main form never displays)

Clicking the Close button on the login form: all the controls on the login form disappear, but the form stays up...?!?

Comment: Apparently your main form is blocking the UI thread when initializing itself.  You'll need to do that work asynchronously, not synchronously.

Comment: Please try the following and let us know what the delay is:  `Application.Run(new Form()); // instead of new frmMain();`  If the delay goes away the issue is the load time on your main form (which is what I suspect).

Comment: Don't call `this.Close` in your OK and Cancel, call `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` or `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pre-loading the main form with as much as you can:

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main()
{
  var mainForm = new frmMain();

  using(loginForm = new frmLogin())
  {
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
      // If they hit "Close" just use the default values for now (for testing)
      HHSConsts.userName = "duckbilled";
      HHSConsts.pwd = "platypus";
      HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = "Packers20Seahawks19";
    }
    else
    {
      HHSConsts.userName = loginForm.UserName;
      HHSConsts.pwd = loginForm.Password;
      HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = loginForm.SiteNumber;
    }
  }

  mainForm.NotifyTheFormInstanceTheCredentialsHaveChangedIfItIsNotEventDrivenAlready();

  Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```