# How can I cleanly shortcircuit my app from a canceled login form, and invoke my main form when login is successful?

Tags: c#, forms, compact-framework, windows-ce, application-shutdown

I have a login form that displays prior to the main form, using this code in Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Unhandled;
    frmLogin loginForm;
    using (loginForm = new frmLogin())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            NRBQConsts.userName = loginForm.UserName;
            NRBQConsts.pwd = loginForm.Password;
            NRBQConsts.currentSiteNum = loginForm.SiteNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit(); // klang!
        }
    }
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}

static void Unhandled(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs exArgs)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
application-wide exception handler: {0}", exArgs.ExceptionObject));
}
```

If the user chooses the "Close" button (rather than attempting to log in), the login form should close, the main form should not display, and the app should shut down. If the user chooses the "OK" button, the login form should close, and the main form should then display.

What happens is choosing the "Close" button causes the app to crash with the clangy, Gong Show-esque "crash" sound. There is this exception msg in my log file:

*Date: 4/9/2009 8:57:51 PM
Message: Reached frmLogin.buttonOK_Click
Date: 4/9/2009 8:57:51 PM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.NullReferenceException: NullReferenceException
   at NRBQ.frmLogin.GetSiteNum()
   at NRBQ.frmLogin.buttonOK_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at NRBQ.Program.Main()*

Here is the pertinent code in the login form:

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{
    public string UserName { get { return textBoxUsername.Text; } }
    public string Password { get { return textBoxPwd.Text; } }
    public string SiteNumber { get { return GetSiteNum(); } }

    private string GetSiteNum()
    {
        String candidateSiteNum = 
    listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(candidateSiteNum))
        {
            candidateSiteNum = "42"; // TODO: Remove before deploying
        }
        return candidateSiteNum;
    }

    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
    frmLogin.buttonClose_Click");
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
    frmLogin.buttonOK_Click");
        if (SanityCheck())
        {
            this.Close(); // closing this login form should make the main 
    form active/visible
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have not yet provided some key data; be 
    sure to enter a username and a password");
        }
    }

    private bool SanityCheck()
    {
        // For now, anyway, no site has to be selected; if none, use "42" by 
    default
        return ((!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxUsername.Text.Trim())))
            && (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPwd.Text.Trim()))));
    }
```

Note: The "OK" button has its DialogResult set to "OK"; the "Close" button has its DialogResult set to "Cancel"

Why does Application.Exit() cause the app to crash? What is the kinder, gentler way to terminate the app?

And why does choosing the Okay button not allow the main form to subsequently display? The login form *does* close, even when selecting the OK button (if the sanity check passes), but that's all...the main form does not display.

### UPDATE

I modified my code, based on the answers below, and now the Cancel works fine (closes the app with no klang/crash), but I'm still not seeing my main form after selecting the "OK" button on the login form, even though I'm programatically setting the DialogResult to OK in the login form code.

Pertinent code below.

PROGRAM.CS

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Unhandled;
    frmLogin loginForm;
    using (loginForm = new frmLogin())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            HHSConsts.userName = loginForm.UserName;
            HHSConsts.pwd = loginForm.Password;
            HHSConsts.currentSiteNum = loginForm.SiteNumber;
            // TODO: Verify that these vals are valid
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
    }
}
```

FRMLOGIN.CS

```
private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmLogin.buttonClose_Click");
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; // <= necessary?
    this.Close();
}

private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmLogin.buttonOK_Click");
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
    if (SanityCheck())
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not yet provided some key data; be 
sure to enter a username and a password");
    }
}
```

This is what I see in my log file:

*Date: 4/9/2009 9:56:47 PM
Message: Reached frmLogin.buttonOK_Click
Date: 4/9/2009 9:56:48 PM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.NullReferenceException: NullReferenceException
   at HHS.frmLogin.GetSiteNum()
   at HHS.frmLogin.get_SiteNumber()
   at HHS.Program.Main()*

As Merle Haggard sang, "*So now it's back, to the coderoom again...*"

### UPDATE 2

I added a messagebox to GetSiteNum():

```
private string GetSiteNum()
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
frmLogin.GetSiteNum()");
    String candidateSiteNum = 
listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // TODO: Remove after testing
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("candidateSiteNum = {0}", 
candidateSiteNum));
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(candidateSiteNum))
    {
        candidateSiteNum = "03"; // TODO: Remove before deploying
    }
    return candidateSiteNum;
}
```

...and I don't see it, so it's blowing up on:

```
String candidateSiteNum = listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

...right after selecting the "OK" button on this login form.

Comment: Try just adding a `bool showForm = true;` up at the top - then instead of `Application.Exit();` just set `showForm = false;`, and finally, wrap an `if (showForm)` around the `Application.Run(new frmMain());`

Comment: Thanks; I'll see if that solves the klang part of the problem...yes, it did. That part is solved.

Comment: FWIW, I warned about this in the last comment in your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-delay-between-an-interspersed-login-form-and-the-ma

Comment: @tcarvin: Aha, you did - thanks for that! I didn't see it until now; if I had, I would have upticked it (I uptick every comment and question, unless they are both rude AND unhelpful, which is quite rare. Unhelpful is somewhat common, and rude a little less so (not from you, from other cats/blokes)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `Close()` against your login form, just set `DialogResult` like below.  Also note that I'm not setting `DialogResult.OK` until **after** `SanityCheck()` tells us we are good to go:

```
    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmLogin.buttonClose_Click");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; 
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmLogin.buttonOK_Click");
        if (SanityCheck())
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
        }
    }
```

You should also make sure an item in the ListBox has been selected in your `SanityCheck()` function:

```
    private bool SanityCheck()
    {
        if (listBoxSitesWithFetchedData.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a site first!");
            return false;
        }

        bool pass = ((!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxUsername.Text.Trim())))
            && (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPwd.Text.Trim()))));
        if (!pass)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have not yet provided some key data; be sure to enter a username and a password");
        }

        return pass;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) say on `Application.Exit`:

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

This means that it will start a nice controlled shutdown - and not exit immediately, causing your code to continue to `Application.Run`, which will apparently then crash and burn.

One option would be to use `Environment.Exit` instead, which will immediately terminate, but it's a messy solution. Another option would be to `return` right after `Application.Exit`, so you never reach `Application.Run`. But still, not very nice.

Instead simply try:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Unhandled;
    frmLogin loginForm;
    using (loginForm = new frmLogin())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            NRBQConsts.userName = loginForm.UserName;
            NRBQConsts.pwd = loginForm.Password;
            NRBQConsts.currentSiteNum = loginForm.SiteNumber;
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
    }
}
```

Returning from `Main` will also exit the application, so nothing else is needed.

Edit: Apparently this wasn't the issue you were having, but anyway, this answers the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never set the Dialog result in your OK button.

Setting your dialog result like this:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

after you sanity check and right before the `this.Close()` should solve the issue since the error is due to a Null reff.

You will also need to set the canceled result other places your form returns (or as I tend to do, on form load, assume a failure until you know its a success and return.)

Comment: Doesn't DialogResult get set to the assigned DialogResult value of the button clicked? That is to say, the value assigned in at design time?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon only on MessageBox.ShowDialog() (there may be others but I am not sure).  If you have a custom form it is never set until you set it.

Comment: Then why would DialogResult be a property?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon because you can call a form as a dialog.  When the form gets initialized the result is NULL until set.  You have to explicitly set it to be able to use it.  The reason it works with MessageBox.ShowDialog() and others (remembered OpenFile and Folder Dialogs as well) is the control sets this when the OK or Cancel button is set.  Its part of the controls class.  When you have a custom class that you create you need to set the DialogResult your self.